# Fullcalendar - Fixed-width events : align left

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm trying to customize a calendar. I will have 4 available events per hour and I wanted to fix their width in order to see easily the available "slots". This is ok with "eventAfterRender" :

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) { 
  $(element).css('width', '25%'); 
},
```

But now, the events are centered, and I want them to be align to the left. But I don't know how to do. Can someone help me ? :)

Here is what I have :

### [image]

... and here is what I should have :)

### [image]

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to "align them left" because, if you examine the CSS for an event, you'll find it's using `position:absolute`. P.S. if you want to shrink the events, you don't need eventAfterAllRender, just set `.fc-event { width: 25%; }` in your CSS file. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3j6k4Lw8/

Comment: Anyway if you are thinking of trying to save space, have you tried using [slotEventOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/slotEventOverlap)? Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3j6k4Lw8/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
I thought I could find a parameter somewhere in order to pull all the items to the left and don't take all the space available.
Actually, the CSS is easier !!! :)
And slotEventOverlap is better but not perfect for what I want. My goal is not only to save space, but also to see easily if there are still places looking at the free slots on the right.

Comment: A space on the calendar doesn't automatically imply a free slot (at least not in FullCalendar's terms. How much free space you see will depend not only on how many events you have at that timeslot, but also on how wide the user's screen is. I'm not sure it's wise to rely on the visuals in this way to denote free space.